# How can I permanently edit the system path?

Tags: c#, windows, setup-project

I'm writing an installer module and I need to add a value to the system %PATH% variable permanently.  How can I modify it from the C# installer code?

Comment: Don't.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Check this link out.. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/256612-path-environment-variable

Comment: @SLaks: I've seen installers do this. What's your opposition to this?

Comment: @SLaks Trying to add my app's bin folder to the path.  I'll play nice.

Answer (score 5):

Well, that's quite yucky.  Modifying the PATH is about as evil a thing an installer could ever do.  It has gotten a particularly bad rap because so many uninstallers destroy it, causing *very* hard to diagnose problems.

I think you'll need to write a custom action that modifies the registry.  The system environment is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, Path value.  You should force a reboot to make sure the new setting is effective.

And test the uninstall.

---

Seeing your comment to SLaks, use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths instead.

Comment: @C.Ross: Notice that even Visual Studio doesn't attempt this. And often I wish that it did sometimes (I have a habit of forgetting to run the VS Command Prompt shortcut).

Comment: ... though something called "Roxio" has done it on this Dell Buisiness machine I'm sitting at right now (not my personal rig).